# Что делать в случае, если ответ затрагивает лишь часть вопроса?

Tags: обсуждение

Что делать в случае, если ответ затрагивает лишь часть вопроса?

Скажем, если вопрос состоит из 2-х частей.

1. Если всего 1 ответ, и он отвечает лишь на половину вопроса.
2. Если ответов 2. Каждый из них отвечает на две разные части вопросов.
3. Если 1 ответ, включающий в себя объяснение половины вопроса. Другая половина в комментариях.

Да, в идеальном случае автор топика должен для каждого вопроса создавать отдельный тред, но не всегда это возможно.

Со стороны автора вопроса что делать? С другой стороны, если есть 1 ответ, затрагивающий половину вопроса. Я даю ответ на другую половину вопроса. Будет ли правильно включить в мой ответ уже существующий ответ по другой части вопроса?

Comment: Если вопрос состоит из двух частей, требуйте от автора разбить его на два вопроса )

Comment: @NickVolynkin тогда может статься, что будет два вопроса с абсолютно одинаковым кодом.

Comment: @Suvitruf: Ну это само по себе не так уж и плохо.

Comment: А если я сейчас возьму и отвечу на 2/3 этого вопроса? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Если всего 1 ответ, и он отвечает лишь на половину вопроса.

На это не отвечаю :)

> 2. Если ответов 2. Каждый из них отвечает на две разные части вопросов.

Вроде тут всё хорошо. Вопрос полностью покрыт.

> 3. Если 1 ответ, включающий в себя объяснение половины вопроса. Другая половина в комментариях.

Переносить из комментариев в ответ. Ну или не трогать.
Я стараюсь сразу дополнять ответ, цитируя соответствующий комментарий.

> Со стороны автора вопроса что делать?

Принимать ту половину, которая ему больше понравилась или содержит больше информации.

> С другой стороны, если есть 1 ответ, затрагивающий половину вопроса. Я даю ответ на другую половину вопроса. Будет ли правильно включить в мой ответ уже существующий ответ по другой части вопроса?

Если есть, что добавить, то можно проигнорировать наличие того ответа и написать.

Если добавить нечего, то на мой взглад, копипастить нечестно. Надо просто упомянуть в своём ответе, что некоторая часть рассмотрена в ответе другого пользователя. Так я предлагаю сделать [в этом случае](/a/2288/178988) и по этой же причине убрал скопипащенный из чужого ответа код, добавленный в мой ответ в третьей [ревизии](//ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/468550/revisions).

Answer (score 5):

> Что делать в случае, если ответ затрагивает лишь часть вопроса?

Я в таких случаях перед ответом ставлю **цитату той части вопроса, на который отвечаю**. К тому же, насколько я понимаю, ни что не мешает ответить на вопрос дважды, закрыв "белые пятна" исходного вопроса.

Дело может быть даже не в том, что в одном вопросе может быть несколько подвопросов. Просто **конкретная формулировка вопроса** может теряться в длинном описании, или среди других мыслей.

Answer (score 2):

В дополнение к [комментарию](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2283/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5-%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%88%D1%8C-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0#comment-6738) от @NickVolynkin хочу сказать, что точно не помешает включить в такой ответ ссылку на ответ, который вы дополняете.