# Изменение вопроса - подмена или дополнение?

Tags: обсуждение

В ответ на обсуждение в комментариях, [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/480924) был изменен.
Ниже скриншоты [изменений](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/480924/revisions).
Является ли такое изменение подменой или это все же дополнение?
Обратите внимание, что первоначальный текст вопроса не менялся.
**Как правильно оформлять дополнения, чтобы избежать обвинений в подмене вопроса?** (Примеры обвинений внизу под скриншотами).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

[тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/480924/#comment553860_480924)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[тут](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2286/?noredirect=1#comment6807_2287)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[тут](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2287/196972)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/480924/#comment554361_480924)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[тут](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2286/?noredirect=1#comment6838_2292)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/481586/?noredirect=1#comment554411_481601)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Сразу оговорюсь, что не вижу смысла рассматривать вопросы с **автоответом** иначе, чем вопросы без него. Просто потому что правила при этом проще и единообразнее.

Я считаю, что на StackOverflow решение о сути вопроса принимает **автор вопроса**, т. к. в общем случае предполагается, что он решает некую проблему, пусть он и не может описать её с первого раза (пресловутая XY-проблема).

Если проблема отличается от того, что на момент написания вопроса удалось сформулировать, а к сформулированному уже опубликовали интересные ответы:

- хочется сразу **отредактировать исходный вопрос**, чтобы уточнить проблему и сделать все ответы (или часть) неприменимыми.

  - Если вопрос выглядел достаточно точно (чтобы не обнаружить XY-проблему), есть все шансы быть обвинённым в растрате ресурсов сообщества (любым из его участников). Отвечающие в этом случае ни в чём не виноваты, а вы просто взяли и свели все их усилия на нет. Конечно, они будут недовольны! Будут обвинения, минусы (а их можно ставить за *всё что угодно*, без оправданий) и **драма**.
  - Если вопрос был туманным (и XY-проблема была очевидна), то отвечающие поторопились. Так бывает.
- можно **задать новый вопрос**, в котором **сослаться на старый** и объяснить, почему решения оттуда не годятся.

  - Полученные ответы может и не решают реальную проблему, но решают описанную в большинстве случаев. Можно дошлифовать вопрос и  **получить плюсов за популярный вопрос**, а реальную проблему, с новыми силами и знаниями, описать отдельно. Если вопрос будет касаться очень редкого случая, он просто не станет популярным и будет пылиться на свалке истории. **Это будет честно.**

#### Решение за автором вопроса, но оно не всегда однозначно.

Можно исходить из собственных нужд, а можно исходить из нужд сообщества. В любом случае, часть ресурсов будет потрачена впустую, но стоит удостовериться, что как можно меньше.

Answer (score 0):

1. Ты хочешь поделиться какой-то информацией и делаешь это.
   При этом ты описываешь только один метод.
2. При той формулировке вопроса оказывается, что 90% случаев покрываются другим, специально предназначенным для этого способом, который ты даже не упоминал.
3. Ещё раз обращаю внимание, что цель вопросов с публикацией собственного ответа - это не решить свою задачу, а поделиться знаниями. Если бы это был обычный вопрос, где автор бы сказал: "Ой, а у меня кнопки отмены нет" - это было бы законной правкой.
4. Но в твоём случае цель другая. Большинство пришедших в этот вопрос из гугла будут иметь диалог с кнопкой отмены. Для них твоё решение будет нерациональным. К тому же, потребует либо выносить обработчик отмены в функцию, либо тупо копипастить код из обработчика клика в код по обработке нажатия esc. Причём, большинство выберет второй способ.
5. Теперь есть два ответа, покрывающие разные стороны вопроса. Это прям соседняя тема на мете: [Что делать в случае, если ответ затрагивает лишь часть вопроса?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2283/178988). По этому поводу я уже высказал там своё мнение: принимать более существенный или больше понравившийся ответ. В данном случае я считаю более ценным ответ про кнопку, поскольку он подходит большинству. Но то, какой ответ принимать - это только твой выбор, в этом убеждать бессмысленно (хотя можно напомнить, что за принятие чужого ответа ты получишь +2, а своего +0; к тому же, принятый собственный ответ всё равно [не закрепляется первым](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1614/178988)).
6. Чтобы разобраться с двумя независимыми ответами, можно просто упомянуть о другом случае в своём ответе, и все будут довольны. Вместо этого ты дополняешь вопрос так, чтобы более частая ситуация под него не подходила.
   Вот просто объясни, в чём ты видишь плюсы этого действия? Я вижу только минусы.
7. Зачем ты каждое последующее дополнение пишешь перед предыдущим? Это выглядит так: "Предыдущее никого не убедило, вот ещё одно, а то я всё равно не удалю - это же *дополнение, а не изменение*". С каждым таким действием ты делаешь тот ответы всё менее подходящими под вопрос.
   По поводу разработки всяких специфических контролов (типа календарей) - их не принято называть диалогами. И что-то у меня большие сомнения, что они будут наследоваться от `Form`, а не от `UserControl`.
8. Что было бы хорошо сделать, я [уже сказал](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2288/178988) - просто внести те же дополнения (хотя что-то их много стало, можно и поменьше) не в вопрос, а в ответ.
   Почему тебя не устраивает этот вариант?

Comment: _"ты даже не упоминал"_ -- а надо было привести все 100500 вариантов, которые можно использовать в специальных случаях? :) _"Большинство пришедших в этот вопрос из гугла"_ -- я так глобально не думал. _"потребует либо выносить обработчик отмены в функцию"_ -- с каких пор это неправильно? :) чем вам один override метода не нравится? думаете, что дизайнер студии из ответа PashaPash накатит меньше кода и в нем разберется "большинство пришедших"? :)

Comment: _"Зачем ты каждое последующее дополнение пишешь перед предыдущим?"_ -- это называется stack (Last In, First Out). Last In - кладется сверху. _"контролов (типа календарей) - их не принято называть диалогами."_ -- контрол находится внутри popup окна. потому что WS_* у контрола не позволяют ему выходить за пределы родителя. а на скриншоте календарь находится за пределами. это значит, что он в контейнере. печально, что мне надо объяснять такие простые вещи.

Comment: _"их не принято называть диалогами"_ -- почти всегда у диалога указан стиль [WS_POPUP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms632600(v=vs.85).aspx). получить стиль окна можно через вызов WinAPI. пример [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/481836)